# How to get all process ids without ps command on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, command, ps

How to get all process ids (pid) (similar to: $ ps aux) but without using `ps`.

One example of when this would be used is when developing a dotnet 5 application to run on a docker host. The dotnet runtime image is a very cut-down Linux image, with `bash`, but without `ps`.  When diagnosing an issue with the application, it's sometimes useful to see what processes are running and if separate processes have been spawned correctly.  `ps` is unavailable on this image.  Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

On Linux, all running process have "metadata" stored in the [/proc filesystem](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html).

All running process ids:

```
shopt -s extglob # assuming bash
(cd /proc && echo +([0-9]))
```

Comment: what is the meaning of echo +([0-9]) .Thanks!

Comment: When I open the filessystems,  there are some other information but how the +([0-9]) get the pid.   Thanks! Sincerely!

Comment: That's a bash [extended filename globbing pattern]() that matches one or more digits. In the /proc directory, there is a subdirectory for each process (named with the numeric pid), and a bunch of other things

Comment: Why was this question closed as unclear? The question seems abundantly clear as evidenced by the on-point answer. Can we get this question reopened?

Comment: It was most likely closed because there is no effort made by the OP. Note the close message: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need"

Comment: Try `for exe in /proc/*/exe; do ls -l $exe; done`

Comment: Want tp clarify that shopt is not included on the current default dotnet docker image

Comment: To also show the command line that started the process, after executing `shopt -s extglob` on its own line, try: `for exe in /proc/+([0-9])/exe; do ls -l $exe; echo "Command line with args:"; tr '\0' '\n' < $(dirname $exe)/cmdline; echo -e '\n'; done`

Answer (score 42):

Further to the comment by @FelixJongleur42, the command

```
ls -l /proc/*/exe
```

yields a parseable output with additional info such as the process user, start time and command.

Answer (score 31):

This one-liner will give you the pid and the cmd with args:

```
for prc in /proc/*/cmdline; { (printf "$prc "; cat -A "$prc") | sed 's/\^@/ /g;s|/proc/||;s|/cmdline||'; echo; }
```

Comment: very nice, thank you!

Comment: In debian it's 
`for prc in /proc/*/cmdline; do (printf "$prc "; cat -A "$prc") | sed 's/\^@/ /g;s|/proc/||;s|/cmdline||'; echo; done`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ivan's example with some filtering:

```
for prc in /proc/*/cmdline; { 
    (printf "$prc "; cat -A "$prc") | sed 's/\^@/ /g;s|/proc/||;s|/cmdline||' | grep java ; echo -n; 
}
```